# Associations in sequelize and creating new persistent instances

Tags: sequelize.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let City = sequelize.define('City', {
        id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true},
    });
    City.associate = (models) => {
        City.belongsTo(models.Country);
    };
    return City;
} 

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
        id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        code: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    Country.associate = (models) => {
        Country.hasMany(models.City);
    };
    return Country;
}
```

I have above models. Now when I create City I am doing this.

```
let country = await Country.findById(input.countryID);
if(country) {
  let city = await City.create({
    name: input.name
  });
  await city.setCountry(country);

  callback(null, city);  
} else {
  callback(new Error('Country does not exist'));
}
```

Instead of doing multiple query for creating city and setting country in city is there a way to directly create city with association to Country in one query? Also I want to populate response after city create to have country as well in it's result.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that simply :**

```
City.create({
    name: input.name ,
    country_id : input.countryID
}).then((data) => { // <----- Inserted if country_id exist in country table as per primary foreign key rule
    // Code for success
}).catch(err => { // Will throw error if condition doesn't match
    // Code for Error
})
```